Ionic Angular SSR , SyntaxError: The requested module './dist/server/main.js' does not provide an export named 'AppServerModuleNgFactory'
I am facing issue in running below code (index.js). I am working on ionic angular and want a ssr feature, so for this i setup the node server and the below my index.js file code.
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } from './dist/server/main'; // Adjust the path here

// Create an Express app
const app = express();

// Define paths to the client-side and server-side bundle files
const browserDir = path.join(__dirname, 'dist/browser');
const serverDir = path.join(__dirname, 'dist/server');
const indexHtml = path.join(browserDir, 'index.html');

// Serve static files from the browser directory
app.use(express.static(browserDir));

// Define a route for SSR
app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Render the Angular app on the server side
    const html = await renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
      document: indexHtml,
      url: req.url,
      extraProviders: [{ provide: 'LAZY_MODULE_MAP', useValue: LAZY_MODULE_MAP }],
    });

    // Send the rendered HTML to the client
    res.send(html);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('SSR error:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

I got below issue.
/home/usernode/.pm2/logs/index-error.log last 15 lines:
0|index    |     at param (/home/usernode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
0|index    | file:///home/usernode/index.js:38
0|index    | import { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } from './dist/server/main.js'; // Adjust the path here
0|index    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
0|index    | SyntaxError: The requested module './dist/server/main.js' does not provide an export named 'AppServerModuleNgFactory'
0|index    |     at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:134:21)
0|index    |     at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:217:5)
0|index    |     at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24)
0|index    | file:///home/usernode/index.js:38
0|index    | import { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } from './dist/server/main.js'; // Adjust the path here
0|index    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
0|index    | SyntaxError: The requested module './dist/server/main.js' does not provide an export named 'AppServerModuleNgFactory'
0|index    |     at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:134:21)
0|index    |     at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:217:5)
0|index    |     at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24)

I have used @angular/ssr npm in my ionic angular project.
version info.
Angular 17
ionic 6
node 18
